# Monitor ajax calls from IE BHO

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, plugins, dom-events, bho

I'm trying to find a way to detect changes on a page from a BHO. For the Firefox version of the plugin I'm using `DomNodeInserted`, but this isn't available in IE. I've also looked at using `onpropertychange`, but this only allows you to monitor a single element (not children).

I'm now wondering if it's possible to monitor when AJAX requests are called. If so, I can make the changes to the page after the AJAX request has completed. Only problem is, I can't find a way to do it.

---

Here's my attempt so far, based on jeffamaphone's suggestions, it doesn't work but maybe it'll jog someone's memory.

```
    public class ChangeMonitor : IHTMLChangeSink {
        public void Notify()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("notified");
        }
    }

    void registerMonitor()
    {
        HTMLDocument document = _webBrowser2.Document;

        ChangeMonitor monitor = new ChangeMonitor();
        IHTMLChangeSink changeSink = monitor;
        IHTMLChangeLog changeLog = null;

        ((IMarkupContainer2)document).CreateChangeLog(changeSink, out changeLog, 1, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE, [onreadystatechange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will work as an equivalent to DomNodeInserted. A DHTML behavior must be attached to the element via htc, but the htc file does not have to exist:

```
document.documentElement.addBehavior("foo.htc");
document.documentElement.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", Notify);
```

The [BHO can inject the script](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18725/Advanced-C-Programming-Developing-IE-Extensions.htm) to handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it, but my theory is you can use [IMarkupContainer2::CreateChangeLog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703624%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This looks interesting, I can't work out how to create one though. Is it registered through IWebBrowser2 somehow?

Comment: the change log only work if you switch to design mode, which in turn disables javascript.