# Internet Explorer Add-on to detect Ajax calls

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

Using the IWebBrowser2 interface is fairly easy to know when navigation took place (OnBeforeNavigate) and finished (OnDocumentComplete). However, a lot of work in browsers are done through Ajax calls (which use XMLHttpRequest).

Is there a way to subscribe to events tracking when an Ajax call occurred and finished in IE?

Comment: Check this out : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/66aee0aa-2c1e-4fa2-9eb3-a4b80481288f

Answer (score 4):

The official way is to create a changelog using an [IHTMLChangeSink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's not complicated, but it's a bit tedious to implement so that you don't lose any requests.

I think the best way to do this may be to [create an HTTP proxy server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2121/How-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-Managed-C), then use [InternetSetOption](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226473) to set the proxy (note that the first argument is `NULL` to set for the current process) to your local HTTP proxy server.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know if that is something that can be transparently done through a BHO and/or policy, without the user having to perform any configuration?

Comment: @OtávioDécio - The HTTP proxy could run inside your BHO that you've configured the `IWebBrowser2` to connect to with `InternetSetOption`; It would not require the user perform any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This previous question seems to provide an answer:

[Monitor ajax calls from IE BHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671412/monitor-ajax-calls-from-ie-bho)

It basically says you have to inject some JavaScript to every page to handle [onreadystatechange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The solution I am looking for should not do anything to the DOM or require any changes to the web application since in many instances we won't have any control over that.

Comment: You don't have to change the webapp. The BHO can [inject the script to any page](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18725/Advanced-C-Programming-Developing-IE-Extensions.htm), whether it's under your control or not.

Comment: I still don't see how that will help me track calls through for example jQuery $Ajax calls...

Comment: You're right. They're talking only about AJAX calls that affect the DOM and track the changes and not the call. [Other resources](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/f5665515-939b-4b61-a80f-e2b97237d614/) suggest going with something like @geocar brought up.